# SelectPicker: mostrar opções já marcadas quando página estiver carregada - AJAX JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Estou usando o [Bootstrap-Select (selectpicker)](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/) e gostaria de saber como faço para que as opções dentro deste selectpicker estejam já marcadas quando a página estiver carregada e o mesmo for clicado.

No caso estou tentando utilizar o método **$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['values']);** para que o selectpicker mostre opções já marcadas conforme dados recebidos em formato JSON proveniente de um script php que passa o resultado para o ajax.

No caso possuo duas tabelas no Mysql: tabela **carros** e tabela **cores**

tabela cores:

```
corID | cor      | 
------------------
01    | Branco   |
02    | Cinza    |
03    | Preto    |
04    | Vermelho |
------------------
```

tabela carros:

```
carroID | carro  | Cor (Foreing Key) e select multiple
-------------------------------------------------------
01      | Gol    | 01, 02, 03
02      | Fiesta | 02, 03, 04
03      | Golf   | 01, 03, 04
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Baseando-se nas duas tabelas acima, gostaria que o campo dropdownlist (selectpicker), já fique marcado com as opções *Branco, Preto, Cinza* referentes ao registro de ID 01 por exemplo. Nesse caso o usuário ao abrir o modal iria poder atualizar este dropdownlist mantendo ou não as opções já marcadas.

No caso, abaixo segue uma função jquery que é executada quando um botão é clicado e um modal é aberto. Quando isso ocorre, dados atrelados a uma ID são mostrados neste modal.

Abaixo segue uma função jquery que abre o modal e mostra dados da tabela *carros*:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){
        var user_id = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_single.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{user_id:user_id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {

                $('#userModal').modal('show');
                $('#carros').val(data.carro);
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', [data.cor]);

            }
        })
    });
```

Quando o modal é aberto, o código acima mostra o dado correto no input *carro* porém no selectpicker não aparece as opções já marcadas conforme o método: **$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', [data.cor]);**.

No caso como fazer para que o selecpicker já carregue além de todas as opções, as opções marcadas conforme dados da coluna *cor* da tabela **carros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver a questão utilizando o método Javascript string split() no método val do selectpicker como abaixo:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', data.cor.split(','));
```

Agora toda vez que o modal abrir, o selectpicker carregará com as opções já marcadas.